Why doesn't this Go code create a deadlock?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int) // Declare the channel inside main()

    wg.Add(4)
    go sender(ch, 42)
    go receiver(ch)

    go sender(ch, 7)
    go receiver(ch)

    wg.Wait()
}

func receiver(ch <-chan int) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    i := <-ch
    fmt.Printf("RECEIVING %v \n", i)
    wg.Done()
}

func sender(ch chan<- int, i int) {
    ch <- i
    wg.Done()
}

What I know so far about Unbuffered channels in go ,is
If the channel is unbuffered, the sender will block until the receiver reads the data from the channel. If the sender tries to send another message before the receiver has read the first one, it will be blocked indefinitely, leading to a deadlock.
is this NOT TRUE ?
Now , I am expecting to get a deadlock from this code , as
Two sender goroutines are launched (sender(ch, 42) and sender(ch, 7)).
Two receiver goroutines are launched (receiver(ch)).
Each sender goroutine sends a value on the unbuffered channel ch.
Each receiver goroutine waits for 5 seconds before attempting to read from the channel.
the sender goroutines send their values immediately, but the receiver goroutines wait for 5 seconds before attempting to read from the channel. Since the channel is unbuffered, this causes the sender goroutines to block indefinitely, leading to a deadlock.
can anybody please explain , why does the above code not create a deadlock ?
Chat-gpt can't help ! could not get it to provide a satisfactory explanation.
JUST to add , I could create the deadlock using
wg.Add(3)
go sender(ch, 42)
go receiver(ch)
go sender(ch, 7)


Thanks in advance .

If the sender tries to send another message before the receiver has read the first one, it will be blocked indefinitely, leading to a deadlock. No. Why would it block indefinitely? It blocks until there is some other goroutine reading the value.

A deadlock can happen only if all goroutines are blocked. time.Sleep does not block, it only blocks temporarily.


If the channel is unbuffered, the sender will block until the receiver reads the data from the channel.

Correct. Strictly, the sender will block until the receiver is ready to read, as the read proceeds directly from the sender to receiver goroutines in the unbuffered channel case. (See the language spec.)

If the sender tries to send another message before the receiver has read the first one, it will be blocked indefinitely, leading to a deadlock.

The second sender will indeed be blocked, but not indefinitely, and no deadlock occurs as the conditions for deadlock are not met – there are not mutual dependencies among different goroutines waiting on the same shared resource. Once the receiver awakes and receives from the channel, at least one sender goroutine is able to proceed.

the sender goroutines send their values immediately, but the receiver goroutines wait for 5 seconds before attempting to read from the channel. Since the channel is unbuffered, this causes the sender goroutines to block indefinitely, leading to a deadlock.

The senders actually do not send their value immediately, as the channel is unbuffered. They must wait for a receiver to read from the channel, at which point the value is conveyed over the channel. This is a subtle distinction but it may help clarify your understanding.
As stated above, the conditions for deadlock are not met because you do not have a cyclic dependency between goroutines. It is true that a sleeping goroutine is not at that moment runnable, but it will become runnable when the timer returns. In respect of the deadlock detector and why it does not cause the program to crash when the goroutines are all temporarily asleep: it will exit early, without reporting deadlock, when there are pending timers, because this indicates that a goroutine will become runnable again at some point in future. You can see this in the source.

Thank you for writing this ;  it clears things up for me.

Wg.Done() line is not executed leading to the Deadlock condition.
Explanation:
While using the channel, if the number of receiver is greater number of sender, the compiler identifies this issue and throw the Deadlock error.
But in case number of receiver is less than sender, the code will get compiled and is ready to run.
But here is the twist, in case sender sends the value in the channel and the receiver doesn't reads the data, it will not execute the next lines.
So, as you mentioned that you are getting the deadlock scenario in case of
wg.Add(3)
go sender(ch, 42)
go receiver(ch)
go sender(ch, 7)
Initially you have Added 4 goroutine to wait , Now when you removed one receiver goroutine,still there is more receiver than sender so the compiler doesnot thrown any error, but while running  wg.Done() function not get executed which leads to Deadlock as the wg.Wait() is waiting in the main thread.
